# Alamofire download progress totalBytesExpectedToRead always -1

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire and found that with the download task and progress I get the correct bytes that it read and the total bytes currently read, but the totalBytesExpectedToRead always -1. Even in the test files the assertion says that this value should be always -1, why?

The download completes with no problem, but I want to show a progress bar while downloading PDF's.

Is it possible that this part of the library is not done yet?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

totalBytesExpectedToRead provides you the Content-Length that is received from server side.
When server does not providing "Content-Length" value in response header then it would be -1 always.
First confirm to webservices and from Web Developers team that they should provide you "Content-Length".

Actually, totalBytesExpectedToRead is give you the value from property of NSURLResponse  of "expectedContentLength"

Comment: So if I only have the URL to a PDF file, and create a download request with Alamofire, this value will be always -1?

Comment: No, this value always be total file size. If it gives you -1 it means server is not providing you size.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll ask the web guys if they added this header to the server's filter.

Comment: @SatishAzad See, I'm downloading the image for the same link, but sometimes totalSize is -1, and sometimes the correct one. Why is this happening?